# Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topic/(?P<name>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, django

My question is about redirection again to a /topics/ page where all entries for topic are located. When I end an entry this code  and reload tab than showing this error is occured as below:

*Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topic/(?P[^/]+)$']*

**how can i solved this?**

at views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import View
from .models import author, catagory, article

# Create your views here.
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = article.objects.all()
        context = {
            "post":post
        }
        return render (request, 'index.html', context)

def getauthor(request, name):
    return render (request, 'profile.html')


def getsingle(request, id):
    return render (request, 'single.html')

def getTopic(request, name):
    return render (request, 'category.html')
```

at urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
from .import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
    #path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name = 'about'),
    path('author/<name>', views.getauthor, name = 'author'),
    path('article/<int:id>', views.getsingle, name = 'single_post'),
    path('topic/<name>/', views.getTopic, name = 'topic'),
]
urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

at index.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Welcome to my django templates {% endblock %}
 {% block content %}
    {% for p in post %}
        <article class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 animate-box">
            <figure>
                <a href="{% url 'single_post' id=p.id %}"><img src="{{ p.image.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </figure>
            <span class="fh5co-meta"><a href="{% url 'topic' p.category.name %}">{{ p.category.name }}</a></span>
            <h2 class="fh5co-article-title"><a href="{% url 'single_post' id=p.id %}">{{ p.title }}</a></h2>
            <span class="fh5co-meta fh5co-date">{{ p.posted_on }}</span>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Modles.py are

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class author(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    details = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username

class catagory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class article(models.Model):
    article_author = models.ForeignKey(author, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField()
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField (auto_now= False, auto_now_add= True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField (auto_now= True, auto_now_add= False)
    catagory = models.ForeignKey(catagory, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: The category name is empty.

Comment: How can solve this?

Comment: Try changing your `{% url 'topic' p.category.name %}` to `{% url 'topic' name=p.category.name %}`

Comment: at first i have use this.
{% url 'topic' name=p.category.name %}

Comment: What is your structure of `p` and the `category` itself? Because `('',)` looks not like an empty name, but a single-element tuple with empty string inside, which is more concerning.

Comment: please kindly show the position where will need to correct

Comment: For an answer to your question it would be helpful if you could post your relevant models

Comment: models.py are updated